# how can i specify that i want a path from the user(just like 'str' or 'int') to pass as an argument in function

Tags: python, function, path, arguments

This is what i Want: as you know in the function definition you can specify the data type that you want from the user to pass as an argument to our function just like the following code:

```
"""function definition"""


def function(data_type: str, data_type2: int, data_type3: float):
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

**Now I want to specify a datatype that if the user does not pass path, in pycharm editor it will show that the datatype passed to the function is not correct.**

**if there is a way please tell me how it is.**

What I have already tried and did not get any desired results i wanted;

```
"""function definition"""


def function(path: dir):
   ...
   ...
   ...
```

anyway,**Is it possible to do it? If not what are other alternatives that i can do it ?**

Comment: `path` is only a `string` - it doesn't have special type. Probably you could only use  `pathlib.Path` or `os.path.exists()` to check if this path exists. But in both situations you can use it only inside function but not to set type of data.

Comment: @furas, Thanks a lot.